# Check transaction committed and if so return a value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, return-value, commit

I want to insert a new user (Email address) into a table of users. If successful (no duplicate), insert basic configurations for new user to other tables, and return some data to client. If not successful, receive relevant notification in dataset in C# project.

Here is sample code so you can easily comment on it

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateUser] 
  @Email nvarchar(256),   
  @Password nvarchar(256)   
AS
BEGIN
  declare @UserID uniqueidentifier;
  declare @ConfigID uniqueidentifier;
  declare @TopMostNode uniqueidentifier;

  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    select @UserID = NEWID();
    select @ConfigID = newid();

    insert into Users (UserID,Email,Password,CurrentConfig) 
      values(@UserID, @Email, @Password, @ConfigID);

    INSERT INTO Configs (ConfigID, OwnerID, DisplayName, LastPrintID)
      VALUES (@ConfigID,@UserID, 'Default Config', 1);

  COMMIT TRANSACTION 
END
```

Comment: You need to elaborate the question more. 1. What kind a notification you will get if the operation is not successful (User exists). 2. What exactly "some data" is that you want to return to the client?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: Hello, No actual problems yet. I want to get notified in client side if transaction was not successful, by means of a false or zero return value, or even an exception. data that I want to return is simply @UserID and @ ConfigID. I didn't know where to put select statement, or do I need to check something before select...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is almost complete.  Just need to add a SELECT to return the new keys.  In case of an error, you will get an exception. EG:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateUser] 
  @Email nvarchar(256),   
  @Password nvarchar(256)   
AS
BEGIN
  declare @UserID uniqueidentifier;
  declare @ConfigID uniqueidentifier;
  declare @TopMostNode uniqueidentifier;

  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    select @UserID = NEWID();
    select @ConfigID = newid();

    insert into Users (UserID,Email,Password,CurrentConfig) 
      values(@UserID, @Email, @Password, @ConfigID);

    INSERT INTO Configs (ConfigID, OwnerID, DisplayName, LastPrintID)
      VALUES (@ConfigID,@UserID, 'Default Config', 1);

  COMMIT TRANSACTION 
  select @UserID UserID, @ConfigID ConfigID;
END
```

Comment: Thanks, So, I get in case transaction not successful, I will get notified by exception in client side.

Comment: Correct.  If either of the statements fails you will get an Exception.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility where you return a recordset with the data you require and a flag to indicate whether the user already existed or not.

```
alter procedure [dbo].[CreateUser]
(
  @Email nvarchar(256)  
  , @Password nvarchar(256)
)
as
begin
  declare @UserID uniqueidentifier, @ConfigID uniqueidentifier, @TopMostNode uniqueidentifier, @UserExists bit = 0;

  select @UserID = UserID, @UserExists = 1 from Users where Email = @Email;

  if @UserExists = 0 begin
    begin transaction;
      set @UserID = newid();
      set @ConfigID = newid();

      insert into Users (UserID, Email, [Password], CurrentConfig) 
        values (@UserID, @Email, @Password, @ConfigID);

      insert into Configs (ConfigID, OwnerID, DisplayName, LastPrintID)
        values (@ConfigID, @UserID, 'Default Config', 1);

    commit transaction 
  end

  -- Return whether the user already exists or not and the user id
  select @UserExists, @UserId

  return 0;
end
```

Another way to return data to the app is using `output` parameters e.g.

```
alter procedure [dbo].[CreateUser]
(
  @Email nvarchar(256)  
  , @Password nvarchar(256)
  , @UserId uniqueidentifier out
  , @UserExists bit out
)
as
begin
  declare @ConfigID uniqueidentifier, @TopMostNode uniqueidentifier;

  set @UserExists = 0;

  select @UserID = UserID, @UserExists = 1 from Users where Email = @Email;

  if @UserExists = 0 begin
    begin transaction;
      set @UserID = newid();
      set @ConfigID = newid();

      insert into Users (UserID, Email, [Password], CurrentConfig) 
        values (@UserID, @Email, @Password, @ConfigID);

      insert into Configs (ConfigID, OwnerID, DisplayName, LastPrintID)
        values (@ConfigID, @UserID, 'Default Config', 1);

    commit transaction 
  end

  return 0;
end
```